# INSERT INTO statement with reserved word as a column name

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, reserved-words

I've got a table (I didn't create it) that I'm trying to insert a new row into. One of the columns is named `DEC`, which is a reserved word in SQL.

I can't change the column name, so I need to be able to make my insert statement work with it. I'm having some issues, though. I've tried single quotes and brackets and backticks, but I can't get rid of the

> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

that I keep getting (presumably because I'm not escaping `DEC` correctly).

This is the insert statement I've got right now:

```
INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, DEC) 
VALUES (spaceObjectName, RA, [DEC]);
```

**EDIT:**
Now using this insert statement:

`INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, [DEC])  VALUES ('spaceObjectName', 'RA', 'DEC');`

and getting this error: `Operation must use an updateable query.`

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  (MySQL, SQL Server, etc)

Comment: You would also need to use [dec] in the column list if this is the issue: `INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, [DEC])`

Comment: `INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, [DEC]) 
VALUES ('spaceObjectName', 'RA', 'DEC');`

Comment: It's SQL Server.  I tried `INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, [DEC])  VALUES ('spaceObjectName', 'RA', 'DEC');` but now it's just giving me this: "Operation must use an updateable query."

Comment: Is there a trigger on `spaceObjectTable`? Or is it a view?

Answer (score 3):

If it's SQL Server, it should be something like

```
INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable 
(spaceObjectName, RA, [DEC]) 
VALUES 
('M-51', 13.5, 47.2);
```

Assuming M-51 (RA and Declination are approximate).

Regarding your current error message: are you using a table, or a view? Do you have permissions for this table?

EDIT: GP tells us data types of RA and DEC columns are strings, so

```
VALUES 
('M-51', '13h 29m 53s', '47deg 11.718min');
```

which is what is used in the edited form of the question, should work.

Comment: Its a table, and RA and Declination are text, not number fields.  I do have permissions for it.

Comment: Then you should have `VALUES ('M-51', '13h 29m 53s', '47deg 11.718min');` or something like that. By the way, if you ever design a table like this, do yourself a favor, and call the columns `RA` and `DECL` and use decimal values (and the SQL Server decimal type) for RA and declination. The `updateable query` error usually means you lack update permissions, but @GarethD might have a point about there being a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes if ANSI SQL mode is enabled, or the proprietary back tick escaping otherwise. (Where to find the ` character on various keyboard layouts is covered in this answer)
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, "DEC") ...
```

or:

```
INSERT INTO spaceObjectTable (spaceObjectName, RA, `DEC`) ...
```